# Dynamic input name validate multiple forms validajs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using validate from jqueryvalidation.org
I have multiple form that are generated via "foreach"
Each form has a unique ID and each input, select, ratio have a unique ID based on form's unique ID..

```
<form id="_idform<?php echo $formid; ?>" >
    <input name="table[<?php echo $formid; ?>][name]" id="inpname<?php echo $formid; ?>">
</form>
```

say I have from 1 to X number of forms with same structure, the only thing that changes is the $formid value based on the requirement.. a use may only use 1, and another might need 20...
Tha is working, what is not "working" is the validation...

```
function validateForm(idForm) {
    // Here is where the magic happen
    // Some what is working but is not validating 100%
    // specially with extended validation...
    let _specialName = 'table['+idform+'][name]'; // <-- What!?
    $('_idform' + idForm).validate({
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function(form){ \
            // save data via ajax 
        },
        rules: {
            _specialName: { 
                required: true, 
                extendedValidation: true 
            }
        },
        messages: {
            _specialName: { 
                required: 'Special message', 
                extendedValidation: 'Your input is not valid' 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The reason for `let _specialName = 'table['+idform+'][name]';` is that I can't use it inside `rules: {}`, the output for that is something like `table[0][name]` which is the name for the input, validatejs does accept names like that but can't handle dynamic names.

```
rules : {
    'table[0][name]': { 
        required: true 
    } // ok
    'table['+idform+'][name]': { 
        requried: true; 
    } // No even on my dreams, not ok.
}
```

That is some what working, it does some kind of validation, but:
1.- it does show the error
2.- it doesn't show the custom message error
3.- it does not validate the extended validations not it show the custom message

Does any one care to help me, point me in the right direction?, please!

Comment: You cannot dynamically insert the names.  When calling `.validate()` to initialize the validation the actual names are supposed to be known.  Since you're constructing the name with `'table['+idform+'][name]'` which apparently is unknown, look at the `.rules()` method for dynamic rule declarations.

Comment: How and where are calling your `validateForm()` function?  The `.validate()` method is meant to be called once on page load to initialize the plugin on your form.  Then validation happens automatically via the built-in event handlers.  It appears like you might believe that you call it whenever you want to validate.

Comment: @Sparky, Yup, i notice that, that is why I'm using variables to retrieve the input name, it does work, it does mark all required inputs but it does not trigger any custom messages or extended validation methods... the validateForm() is called when user clicked on the submit button, `e.preventDefault(); let _id = $(this).data('formid'); let _valid = validateForm(_id);`, .... like I said, it some what it working... I'll keep looking, thank you.

Comment: That's one problem.  You **should NOT** be calling validate on submit.  The validate plugin is **initialized** via the `.validate()` method on **page load** and then the submit event is captured automatically by the plugin.  I suggest that you read the examples posted on the SO wiki page and the thoroughly review the official documentation.